# Write commands (i.e. input not output) to a file

Tags: powershell

The [Out-File](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849882.aspx) lets us write output to a file. What if we want to write input to a file?

I want a list of all the commands that I wrote during a PowerShell session. The file should look something like this:

```
dir
cd
ni myFile.txt -t file
cd..
```

We want to keep track of what commands we use in PowerShell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Get-History |
 select -ExpandProperty commandline |
 Add-Content commandhistory.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of `Start-Transcript` and `Stop-Transcript`

Technet links about each command: [start-transcript](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849687.aspx) and [stop-transcript](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849688.aspx)

Usage example: `Start-Transcript -Path C:\Folder\Transcript.txt`